# NSButton Argument binding not working

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsbutton

I am trying to perform an action on a button using bindings, so I declared and defined following method in my app-controller class:

```
- (void)selectFolderAtPath:(NSString *)path;
```

And I did following bindings on button, in IB:

```
Argument:

Bind to: App Delegate
Model Key Path: sourcePath (this is a NSString property)
Selector Name: selectFolderAtPath:
```

Target:

```
Bind to: App Delegate
Model Key Path: self
Selector Name: selectFolderAtPath:
```

**Problem is -** if I de-select 'Argument' binding then only method is getting invoked, otherwise it is not working.

**Can any one suggest me -** how can I pass a NSString as argument to the method invoked, using cocoa-bindings?

Comment: If you don't deselect the "argument" binding, what happens?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: Hard to say what's wrong then -- I set up a button and method according to your post, and it worked fine for me.  When the argument is bound, is the button enabled?

Comment: no.. in the beginning it is disabled...I need to deselect this binding option to enable it - Conditionally Sets Enabled

Comment: Deselect the Conditionally Sets Enabled check box -- mine didn't work either with that selected

Comment: I deselected it... but it did n't work.. can you share your project with me? ... I am doing it with XCode 4.2 and using ARC

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9417/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-miraaj)